# Как соединить 2 контейнера docker

Tags: docker, redis

У меня есть контейнер с redis, который я назвал redis_2 и контейнер со своим docker_id, я хочу, чтобы мой контейнер смог делать запросы в redis. Как я могу это сделать? (Я новичок в докере и пока не очень понимаю многие аспекты)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно чтобы оба контейнера были в одной сети и делать запросы к редис по имени контейнера или по имени сервиса.

Проверить в какой сети контейнер можно при помощи команды:

```
docker container inspect ИМЯ_КОНТЕЙНЕРА
```

Если вы запускаете контейнеры при помощи docker-compose, то по дефолту оба контейнера будут в одной сети.
Если запускаете контейнеры при помощи команды `docker run`, то используйте ключ [--network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) чтобы поместить контейнер в нужную вам сеть.